# Confirm action for modal button asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, prompt

I am trying to add a prompt when a user clicks the "cancel" button on the modal below. 
It prompts them to confirm the action. The code below is what I have currently attempted.

```
function ShowAddEditExecutive() {
        $("#addEditExecutive").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 800,
            appendTo: "form",
            open: function () {
                $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").show();
                // Removes the do you want to leave this page dialog.
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
                // The two isplalines below are 2 different ways to ensure the 
                // background is completely grayed out if the modal is larger
                // then the page. The first was chosen so that the scroll
                // bars are not disabled.
                $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'fixed');
               //$('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            },
            buttons: {
                "Add/Edit Executive Information": function () {
                    $("[id*=btnAddEditExecutive]").click();
                },
                "Cancel": function () {

                    $(this).dialog("close");

                }
             },
        close: function (ev, ui) {
            // Ensures when you cancel that the values are not retained.
            $(this).remove();
            // The two lines below are 2 different ways to ensure the 
            // background is completely grayed out if the modal is larger
            // then the page. The first was chosen so that the scroll
            // bars are not disabled.
            $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('position', 'absolute');
            //$('body').css('overflow', 'inline');
        },

    });


    }
```

Comment: what's the problem with the code?

Comment: There is no issue with this code, I'm trying to make it so that the "cancel" button raises a confirmation window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to create a native way to confirm action, you can use `confirm` to prompt user to choose to continue or not, here's what should you do in your code

```
"Cancel": function () {
    if(confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel ?"))
    {
        //code if yes
        $(this).dialog("close");
    }
    else
    {
        //code if no, don't do anything in your case, or don't use the else
    }
}
```

here's the [usage example](http://jsfiddle.net/dthgt1xo/).

the other way if you want to make it look the same with your design, you could create a custom `<div>` which contain confirmation text of whether the user agree or want to continue or not, then `style` it using the `CSS` and using the `jQuery onclick function` to handle the event.

Comment: You sir are a saint. THank you